# How do I use a type from a DLL file?

Tags: c++, dll, typedef, loadlibrary, getprocaddress

I have a DLL file without a header file, only sdk with code examples and function signatures. So I use `LoadLibrary()` to load my DLL: `HINSTANCE myLibrary = LoadLibrary(_T("MyDLL.dll"));`. Then I use `GetProcAddress()` to get pointers to the functions from the DLL: `INITIAL initial = (INITIAL)GetProcAddress(myLibrary, "initial");` having used `typedef` beforehand: `typedef int(__cdecl* INITIAL)(TCHAR*, INT);`

Then I can finally use my functions and they work perfectly fine.

However I have stumbled upon functions that either return or use a custom data type as an argument:

```
UnfamiliarType myFunction1();
int myFunction2(UnfamiliarType arg);
```

How am I supposed to handle that if there is no information about this data type in sdk? If I get to know what fields this datatype has, do I also use `typedef` and `GetProcAddress`?

I suspect that the `UnfamiliarType` is some sort of an ID wrapper judging by its use, so if I had to guess, it might look something like `UnfamiliarType(long id)`.

Comment: Short answer: you cannot. If the type is not defined in a header file, you cannot use it.

Comment: Ask the SDK vendor for documentation (preferably in the form of a header file), otherwise it's not much good as a software _development_ kit.

Comment: the return slot is allocated by the caller, you can't call the function unless you know `sizeof(UnfamiliarType)`, if you do know the size then you can define an opaque type of the same size to be able to call the function, but you won't be able to fully use that object, you need the header to be able to fully use it.

Comment: @AhmedAEK: You are assuming calling conventions there. You don't even know with a random DLL how the space for return values is allocated.

Comment: A DLL doesn't have types. The types are in the sources, in particular in the header files. Ask the vendor of the SDK to send you the missing header file(s). If they don't, just use a different product. Because why on earth would you trust someone who supplies a development library without headers?